# Strange Character in SQL Database

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a WPF C# application that saves and retrieves data in and out of a SQL Database. Everynow and then a strange character turns up in the DB. I'm assuming it happens when incorrect data is passed into it, but it throws no error, and when I try to retrieve that row its like its not there, or doesn't exist.

I am unable to paste the character but it looks like an empty square.

Can anyone shed any light on this?

Comment: Sounds like a character set problem. Are the character set definitions of the input, database and output the same?

Comment: What collation are you using for the field with this problem? What encoding are you using in your code? What encoding is the data in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like an encoding problem. Have a read here and see if you can deduce what's wrong afterwards: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html