# Issues reading a string with weird characters in SQL Server 2008 and previous versions

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unicode

Here is my issue today: we load some info from text files into a SQL Server table. The thing is that for a field I realized that the string value is a little bit weird.

When I query the table with a SQL Server client 2008 or previous, I got this result set:

[image]

Even if I try to run a query like this one below, the resultset is empty:

```
select REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(cust_po)), '  ', ' ') 
from dbo.test_char
where cust_po like '%076929%'
```

The weird thing is: with SQL Server 2016, just opening the table looks normal, although the query doesn't return any results either:

[image]

Now, following a couple of instruction from @SolomonRutzky I have performed the query below to get a result in varbinary

[image]

the new result is : 0x300037003600390032003900BC05BC05BC05BC05BC05BC05BC05BC05BC05

how could get that as a varchar without the weird chars or space or wherever that is?

Comment: Did this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7159227/strange-character-in-sql-database

Comment: Why do you show a query result for SSMS 2008 but the table editor for SSMS 2016? It would be helpful to see the same output as the first image but for SSMS 2016 (since you are making a distinction there). BUT, instead of the query that you originally used, execute the following and then post the image of the result: `SELECT cust_po, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), cust_po, 2) FROM dbo.test_char;`. I'm also curious as to why the column header is `(no column name)`. Was that an expression? And what datatype and Collation is the `cust_po` column?

Comment: Hey @SolomonRutzky thanks so much for that interaction. Well, look about why the different visualization is cuz I was working in different instances version so well I didn't realize that but thanks for the advice. I tried your query but the return message was 'Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type nvarchar to varbinary.' this is SQL 2008. Finally about the expression is the same  column cust_po. the type is nvarchar as you can see in the message. thanks buddy

Comment: Ok. I made a minor mistake with that CONVERT function. Try this instead: `SELECT cust_po, CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), cust_po) FROM dbo.test_char;`

Comment: Yeahp @SolomonRutzky that runs and convert that to binay but now how could get that in readable data as varchar?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "readable data as varchar". You can just copy and paste the results grid into the question. Put it in a code block (i.e. each line indented 4 spaces)

Comment: check it out @SolomonRutzky thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### What is going on?

Now that the `VARBINARY` representation of the data has been posted, the issue is much clearer.

As we can see, the two lines with the "odd" characters are:

```
0x300037003600390032003900BC05BC05BC05BC05BC05BC05BC05BC05BC05
```

This column is `NVARCHAR` which means that the encoding is UTF-16 Little Endian. Being UTF-16 means that we look at each block of 2 bytes (characters will either be 1 or 2 sets of those 2-byte blocks), and being Little Endian means that the bytes in each 2-byte block are in reverse order. Meaning, the first character is `3000` (which is 2 bytes), and that equates to Code Point U+0030, which is the number `0`. The next character is `3700` which is Code Point U+0037 which is the number `7`. And so on down through `3900` which is the final `9` in the value.

But then we get to nine sets of `BC05` which is Code Point U+05BC, which is [Hebrew Point Dagesh or Mapiq](https://unicode-table.com/en/05BC/). And this is where it gets interesting as there are three separate things going on here:

1. What is displayed is a function of the font being used. And not all fonts handle all characters correctly, or even have mappings for all characters. This is why you see a series of circles to the left in the Results Grid, and a single dot on the far left in the row editor (hard to see, especially if you don't know to look for it, but look closely in the row editor image and the top two lines both have a tiny dot to the left of the `0`).
2. Hebrew is a Right-to-Left language, which explains why the circles in the Results Grid are on the left, even though the characters in the data come after the numbers.
3. This particular character is a combining character, which means that it is supposed to attach to the character that precedes it. Since different fonts display characters differently you get the variation that you are seeing between the Results Grid and row editor. The Results Grid font does not seem to be handling this character correctly, while the row editor does. But, in handling it correctly, we see that this combining character does not allow for showing multiples, so all we see is a single dot on the far left instead of 9 dots (but all 9 are there, just one on top of the other.

To see this in action, the following query:

```sql
SELECT N'4   11' + REPLICATE(NCHAR(0x05BC), 10) + N'  88  f ';
```

returns:

## 4   11ּּּּּּּּּּ  88  f

Notice the single dot on the left side of the second `1`. There is only a single dot even though the string has 10 of them (due to the `REPLICATE`). Well, that is what my browser is showing, captured as the following image:

[image]

Yet I see the following in my Results Grid:

[image]

Notice how the dot is to the left of the first, not second, `1`, AND the placement of the `11` between the `88` and the `f`,

And, if I copy and paste from the Results Grid into the Query Editor, I see:

[image]

Notice that there are several red dots.

### Why doesn't `where cust_po like '%076929%'` return any rows?

This is due to the string comparison doing what it should do and applying linguistic rules. It doesn't matter what order the bytes are in, what matters is how that rendered string is viewed from a human reading it perspective. And since this particular character is a combining character, it does not come after the preceding character, it is part of it. Meaning, the second `9` in your `076929` value isn't a `9` anymore, it is `9` + Dagesh.

```sql
SELECT 1 WHERE
N'123' + REPLICATE(NCHAR(0x05BC), 5) LIKE N'%123' + REPLICATE(NCHAR(0x05BC), 4) + N'%';
-- no rows returned

SELECT 2 WHERE
N'123' + REPLICATE(NCHAR(0x05BC), 5) LIKE N'%123' + REPLICATE(NCHAR(0x05BC), 5) + N'%';
-- 2

SELECT 3 WHERE N'9' + NCHAR(0x05BC) = N'9'
-- no rows returned
```

### How do you get rid of those characters?

Assuming that this U+05BC character is the only issue in your data, you can do a simple replace. You have already tried this, but `REPLACE` isn't finding a match. When this happens, you need to use a binary Collation as shown here:

```sql
SELECT REPLACE(N'4   11' + REPLICATE(NCHAR(0x05BC), 5) + N'  88  f ',
               NCHAR(0x05BC) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2,
               N'~');
-- 4   11~~~~~  88  f
```

Comment: Wow what amazing explanation super good man, but now how replace these dots or U+05BC symbols in my query to get all from the string all except the hebrew point? thanks buddy

Comment: I'm trying this select 
cust_po,
REPLACE(cust_po, NCHAR(0x05BC) ,'') as 'test'
from dbo.test_char       Unfortunatelly it doesnt work and the solutions suggested by @Alan in the post below is too complex with tables and cross. thanks my friend

Comment: man @Solomon Rutzky there's nothing like solved and super like here but what an amazing job, not only help to me to figure it out, besides you help me to understand why with very explicit examples and super clear info. brother one of my favorites answers and from now you got a new follower. thanks man

Comment: @AndresAngel You are welcome. And thank you for those kind words :). And just FYI, I recently started a blog at: https://SqlQuantumLeap.com/

Answer (score 1):

First - you're in good hands when you have @solomon Rutzky looking at your code ;)

I don't have an NVarchar version of this at the moment but, if you only want the numeric values in your column you could use [DigitsOnlyEE](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/scripts/String+Function/141686/). The solution would look something like this.

```
-- sample data with a couple characters to screw you up. 
DECLARE @table TABLE (somestring nvarchar(100));
INSERT @table
SELECT CONCAT(NCHAR(365), '123') UNION ALL
SELECT CONCAT(CHAR(0), '789');

-- solution
SELECT *
FROM @table t
CROSS APPLY dbo.DigitsOnlyEE(t.somestring);
```

Results:

```
somestring   DigitsOnly
------------ ------------
ŭ123         123
 789         789
```

Comment: amazing. thanks so much I appreciate. however this solution needs to cross a table with my query and that is very expensive. I was thinking in something more like select 
cust_po,
REPLACE(cust_po, NCHAR(0x05BC) ,'') as 'test'
from dbo.test_char

Comment: Thanks to you for the feedback. If the only bad character is NCHAR(0x05BC) then using REPLACE will be the better way to go for sure.

Comment: @AlanBurstein Thank you for those kind words at the top of your answer. That is quite the compliment, and it is much appreciated 